# ¿Alguien sabe que lenguaje interpreta la impresora de etiquetas Brother QL_700?

Tags: java, impresión

Estoy creando un programa en java y necesito saber que lenguaje interpreta la impresora brother ql_700 para mandarle a imprimir textos, ya que en su documentacion solo dice que maneja un lenguaje propio.

Comment: Tras una simple busqueda en Google: [documentacion](http://download.brother.com/welcome/docp000678/cv_qlseries_eng_raster_600.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Segun la documentación oficial maneja un lenguaje propio, no creo tiene nombre, pero ellos lo llaman: Brother QL series Command Reference.

Puedes revisar los comandos disponibles en:

http://download.brother.com/welcome/docp000678/cv_qlseries_eng_raster_600.pdf